# Python Paramiko directory walk over SFTP

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

How to do `os.walk()` but on another computer through SSH? The problem is that `os.walk()` executes on a local machine and I want to ssh to another host, walk through a directory and generate MD5 hashes for every file within.

What I wrote so far looks like this (below code) but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
try:
    hash_array = []
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('sunbeam', port=22, username='xxxx', password='filmlight')

    spinner.start()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(_path):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root), file)
            
            #  generate hash code for file
            hash_array.append(genMD5hash(file_path))
            
            file_nb += 1
    spinner.stop()
    spinner.ok('Finished.')

    return hash_array
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return None
finally:
    ssh.close()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To recursively list a directory using Paramiko, with a standard file access interface, the SFTP, you need to implement a recursive function with a use of [`SFTPClient.listdir_attr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.listdir_attr):

```
from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
```

```
def listdir_r(sftp, remotedir):
    for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(remotedir):
        remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry.filename
        mode = entry.st_mode
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            listdir_r(sftp, remotepath)
        elif S_ISREG(mode):
            print(remotepath)
```

*Based on [Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848#50130813)*.

---

Alternatively, [pysftp](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/) implements an `os.walk` equivalent: [`Connection.walktree`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.walktree).

---

Though you will have troubles getting MD5 of a remote file with SFTP protocol.

While Paramiko supports it with its [`SFTPFile.check`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile.check), most SFTP servers (particularly the most widespread SFTP/SSH server – OpenSSH) do not.
See:
[How to check if Paramiko successfully uploaded a file to an SFTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28967969/850848) and
[How to perform checksums during a SFTP file transfer for data integrity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30056566/850848)

So you will most probably have to resort to using shell `md5sum` command (if you even have a shell access). And once you have to use the shell anyway, consider listing the files with shell, as that will be magnitudes faster then via SFTP.

See [md5 all files in a directory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36920307/850848).

Use [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command):
[Comparing MD5 of downloaded files against files on an SFTP server in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62475321/850848)

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848)*.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672923/3206414), here a version that does not require recursivity and returns a list of paths instead using the `print` command.

```py
from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
from collections import deque

def listdir_r(sftp, remotedir):
    dirs_to_explore = deque([remotedir])
    list_of_files = deque([])

    while len(dirs_to_explore) > 0:
        current_dir = dirs_to_explore.popleft()

        for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(current_dir):
            current_fileordir = current_dir + "/" + entry.filename

            if S_ISDIR(entry.st_mode):
                dirs_to_explore.append(current_fileordir)
            elif S_ISREG(entry.st_mode):
                list_of_files.append(current_fileordir)

    return list(list_of_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another implementation that tries to mimic the [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) ([`python/cpython/os.py:walk`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/897e716d03d559a10dd5015ecb501ceb98955f3a/Lib/os.py#L282-L431)) function in Python so that it can be used as a drop-in replacement for code that expects the built-in function.

```py
class ParamikoWalkExample:
    def __init__(self, host, username=None):
        self._host = host
        self._username = username
        self._ssh = self._ssh_connect()
        self._sftp = self._ssh.open_sftp()

    def _ssh_connect(self):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.connect(self._host, username=self._username)
        return ssh

    def walk(
        self,
        top,
        topdown=True,
        onerror=None, # ignored
        followlinks=False,
    ):
        stack = [top]

        while stack:
            top = stack.pop()
            if isinstance(top, tuple):
                yield top
                continue

            dirs = []
            nondirs = []
            walk_dirs = []

            for entry in self._sftp.listdir_attr(top):
                if entry.st_mode is None:
                    nondirs.append(entry.filename)
                elif stat.S_ISDIR(entry.st_mode):
                    dirs.append(entry.filename)
                    walk_dirs.append(top + '/' + entry.filename)
                elif stat.S_ISREG(entry.st_mode):
                    nondirs.append(entry.filename)
                elif stat.S_ISLNK(entry.st_mode):
                    target = entry.filename
                    while True:
                        target = self._sftp.readlink(target)
                        if not target:
                            nondirs.append(entry.filename)
                            break
                        target_entry = self._sftp.stat(target)
                        if not target_entry.st_mode:
                            nondirs.append(entry.filename)
                            break

                        if stat.S_ISLNK(target_entry.st_mode):
                            continue

                        elif stat.S_ISDIR(target_entry.st_mode):
                            dirs.append(entry.filename)
                            if followlinks:
                                walk_dirs.append(top + '/' + entry.filename)
                            break
                        elif stat.S_ISREG(target_entry.st_mode):
                            nondirs.append(entry.filename)
                            break

            if topdown:
                yield top, dirs, nondirs
                for new_path in reversed(walk_dirs):
                    stack.append(new_path)
            else:
                # Yield after sub-directory traversal if going bottom up
                stack.append((top, dirs, nondirs))
                for new_path in reversed(walk_dirs):
                    stack.append(new_path)
```

---

Side note: the built-in function was recently rewritten on main branch to use a stack instead of recursion due to to recursion errors in deep file hierarchies: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89727